# How to run Code-First Migrations from a psake build?

Tags: entity-framework, powershell, entity-framework-migrations, psake

I can type `Update-Database`, `Enable-Migrations` etc, from Package Manager Console and it works fine.

If I need to do the same from a regular powershell session, or in a psake build file, then how do I do it?

I tried importing the module `EntityFramework.5.0.0\tools\EntityFramework.psm1` from the packages directory, and I did get the `Update-Database`, `Enable-Migrations` functions, but I cannot supply their arguments - they need a project, source, and 6 more - and there is no documentation whatsoever. Can I not automate the database deploy on some machine in our CI chain ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with importing the module into a PowerShell console is that I believe the module expects to run in a context where it has a Visual Studio DTE object available. That environment is the NuGet Package Manager Console.  This issue has been brought up before.  Check out this [blog post](http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/05/thoughts-on-installing-and-updating.html) and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386672/using-nuget-to-update-project-files-outside-of-package-manager-console).

This [blog post shows how to write code that does migrations](http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/).

Comment: Hey thanks for answering, So is the only way to run migrations from build scripts is by generating SQL, and using that?

Comment: @Zasz I don't know if that is the only way but it certainly is one way that would work.  Check out these two blog posts: http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/ef-code-first-migrations-update-database-outside-of-visual-studio/ and http://romiller.com/2012/02/09/running-scripting-migrations-from-code/

Comment: Awesome~! the second link post deserves more recognition - I was about to write my own tool which will do the migrations after looking at the 1st link, that I can call from build scripts - and the second link pointed me to the already developed tool :)

Comment: @Zasz Good suggestion. I put that link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `migrate.exe` from EntityFramework NuGet package.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14139229/991267

Comment: you can update-database from migrate.exe on the command line but you can't enable-migrations (or add-migration) this way.