# Trying to run EF Code first Migrate.exe tool on production environment failed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using EntityFramework version 6.1.3.

I copied migrate.exe from EntityFramework version 6.1.3 package tool folder to bin folder of my website.

My web site is compiled and published to production environment with x86 CPU and target framework 4.5.1

I run the following command:

> D:\Sites\MatrixPortal\bin>migrate.exe
>   d:\sites\MatrixPortal\bin\MatrixPortal.BL.dll
>   /startUpDirectory="d:\Sites\MatrixPortal\bin"
>   /startUpConfigurationFile="d:\Sites\MatrixPortal\Web.config"

and i get the following error:

> ERROR: Could not load file or assembly
>   'd:\sites\MatrixPortal\bin\MatrixPortal.BL' or one of its
>   dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

EDIT:

when i try this:

> migrate MatrixPortal.BL.dll /verbose

i get other error:

> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'MatrixPortal.BL' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to
>   load a program with an incorrect format. File name: 'MatrixPortal.BL' 
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.LoadAssembly(String
>   name)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.BaseRunner.FindConfiguration()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run() 
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate
>   callBackDelegate)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = MatrixPortal.BL  (Partial) WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an
>   assembly: WRN: Assembly Name: MatrixPortal.BL | Domain ID: 2 WRN: A
>   partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is
>   provided. WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect
>   assembly. WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual
>   identity for the assembly, WRN: that consists of the simple name,
>   version, culture, and public key token. WRN: See whitepaper
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and
>   common solutions to this issue. LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///D:/Sites/MatrixPortal/bin/ LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>   Calling assembly : EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: Using application configuration file:
>   C:\Users\guy_b\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpC402.tmp LOG: Using host
>   configuration file:  LOG: Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private,
>   custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind). LOG: Attempting
>   download of new URL
>   file:///D:/Sites/MatrixPortal/bin/MatrixPortal.BL.DLL. ERR: Failed to
>   complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
>
> ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'MatrixPortal.BL' or one of its
>   dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
>   format.

also tried this:
http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/command-line-entity-framework-code-first-migrations/

and created a file called Redirect.config with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" culture="neutral" />
                                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0-6.1.3" newVersion="6.1.3" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

but got the same error as above :(

Comment: Here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx) it says "This can be caused by specifying an assembly name incorrectly"

Comment: Also, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794084/getting-migrate-exe-to-work

Comment: thanks @miparnisari, I've asked this question after reading those above, I've double checked my assembly name and wasted hours of trying to run this tool in many ways like Zasz 's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

I've Published the web site project with x86 target cpu, and apparently it wasn't really x86, i don't know why, maybe a bug?

After changing Publish to any cpu it worked. i was able to run migrate.exe without an error using the following arguments:

```
migrate.exe MatrixPortal.BL.dll /verbose /startUpDataDirectory="D:\Sites\MatrixPortal" /startUpConfigurationFile="D:\Sites\MatrixPortal\Web.config"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I got the error because I wrote `migrate .\MyAssembly.dll` instead of `migrate MyAssembly.dll`.

See [Common Problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/migrate-exe#common-problems) documentation section.