# migrate.exe ignoring binding redirects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-assembly, assembly-binding-redirect

I am trying to run the `migrate.exe` application from `EntityFramework` on a specific DLL. This DLL references the `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey` nuget package.

When I try to run the command

```
./migrate MyProject.Data /startUpDirectory=C:\myDir /startUpConfigurationFile=C:\myDir\Redirect.config
```

I get the following error

> ERROR: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6ae ed' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Excep tion from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

Normally I would say that this is because it is looking for version 6 of `Newtonsoft.Json` and cannot find it. But I have a binding redirect that points to the latest version.

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

So, I dont understand why this would not redirect to version `9.0.0.0` and it only looks for version `6.0.0.0`.

I have decompiled the `Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.WebKey.dll` and I can see that it is referencing version `6.0.0.0` so that is **WHY** its looking for that version but I cant see why it isn't redirecting.

Comment: I have also faced the same problem.did you resolved the error. if you resolved the error can you please post your answer.

Comment: This answer to a similar question might be useful to you (particularly if your assembly is .net 4.0): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794084/getting-migrate-exe-to-work#12270108