# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

Tags: entity-framework, json.net, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to executing Entity Framework migrations from VSTS Release Management, for that I followed this [link](http://www.lfraile.net/2016/10/im-back-executing-entity-framework-migrations-from-vsts-release-management/).

I configure this task in this way, before the deploying task for the application:

[image]

During release process I got the Exception, after executing the above task.

**System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)**

In my Project I used the **Newtonsoft.Json** version as **9.0.1** because other DLL’s dependent on this version. So I strict to use the same version of **Newtonsoft.Json**.

**app.config**

```
       <dependentAssembly>

          <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />

          <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.1" newVersion="9.0.1" />

      </dependentAssembly>
```

Before posting question here I search in Google and find out some the links related my issue but those are not helpful to resolve this issue.

[Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507189/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-newtonsoft-json-version-4-5-0-0-culture-neutr?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)

I found similar issue in stack overflow but nobody can't post answer for that. This is the link for that question 
[migrate.exe ignoring binding redirects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679656/migrate-exe-ignoring-binding-redirects)

Can you please tell me how to resolve the above error as soon as possible?

Comment: Could you add your packages.config and `<assemblyBinding>` section from your web/app.config?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue, what's the result if you try it with a new project? I shared a simple project on the OneDrive, you can try again with it and check the result. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhSz-Mo-ZCrXBEGEJ

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT, I am not getting the issue in my local machine. the issue occurred during VSTS release management.

Comment: Both of these ways work fine for me. Try it with my project and check the result.

Comment: If it doesn't work, share the detail log fine on the OneDrive.

Comment: Thanks @starain-MSFT, I tried with your project but I did not any issues because in your project there is no code related to initialize the azure key vault provider. But in my original project there is a code related to initialize the azure key vault provider. I shared logs on the one drive https://1drv.ms/t/s!At-JUB9_wu9CvTtQeV5XGDPbHHhs

Comment: I find the question in stack overflow similar to my issue. This is link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679656/migrate-exe-ignoring-binding-redirects

Comment: I can reproduce this issue, could you configure migration database through publish profile? (Right click project > Publish > Check Execute Code First Migrations option in settings section)

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you have something like

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"  publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

In your app/web.config

You will need to make sure that you change the `6` to a `9` so that your app looks for the correct/installed version, e.g.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"  publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I used the same version you mentioned in the second code snippet as well.

Comment: It would still be nice to see your `packages.config`

Comment: But its not working. still I got the same error in VSTS during release creation.

Comment: @pradeep please add your packages.config.

Comment: In packages.config, This is line for Newtonsoft.Json DLL  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />

Comment: Ah, so you're actually using 9.0.1 not 9.0.0 as stated in your question. Try updating the oldVersion and newVersion attributes to use 9.0.1. However your app is still expecting version 6.0.0... Hmm

Comment: Just now I checked in nuget its already 9.01 version is installed of Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Updated app.config file with 9.0.1 version. but still I faced the same problem.