# How to use code first migrations on DB when using webapi 2 and ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I am using ef core along with web api 2 and i want to do automatic migrations and dont want to run any commands manually.

I have followed this [migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17020393/asp-net-mvc-4-migrations-how-to-run-update-database-on-a-production-server)

and want to use the following code during application startup to fix my issue

```
 System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, Configuration>());
```

But `Database` class is from entity framework. I dont want to use entity framework because i am already using ef core. Is there any other way of doing the same?

Comment: Read here for more details: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6214

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
context.Database.Migrate();
```