# Can't run code first migrations using migrate.exe

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I'm trying to update a database on a test system.  When I run `update-database` in visual studio things work as expected.

When I deploy and then try to run on a test machine:

```
Migrate.exe CodeFirst.dll /startupConfigurationFile="..\web.config"
```

I get:

> no connection string named xxx could be found in the application config file

...even though there is a connection string with that name in the web.config.  There is only one .config file, there isn't a config file for the dll that I'm running against

I attempted to declare my connection string manually:

```
Migrate.exe CodeFirst.dll /connectionString="Data Source=192.168...;Initial Catalog=Database;" /connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

but that still gave the the same error for some reason...  Is it ignoring the connection string that I'm passing in and trying to look for one again?  Why would it do that?

<strike>but that gave me a really weird error:</strike>

> The migrations configurations type "Source=192.168... could not be
>   found in the assembly CodeFirst.dll
>   I wondered if it had something to do with spaces, so I tried changing 'data source' to 'server' and Initial Catalog to 'database' but that didn't help.

edit: fixed quotation marks

I've seen similar questions but they were all about running inside of visual studio and I have no issues when trying to do that.  Any more ideas of what I can do?  Has anyone gotten either of these options to work?

Comment: do you have the non standard quotes in the commandline?

Comment: I guess I did.  Fixing that though, just results in the initial error again for some reason.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Finally got this to work with Entity framework 6.1.3.  I'm not sure if the version really matters, but we ended up downloading the code and debugging against that.

What really made the difference was using the full path in both of the paths required...   Hope that can help someone!

```
migrate CodeFirst.dll Configuration /startUpDirectory:"C:\src\app\CodeFirst\bin\Debug" /startUpConfigurationFile:"C:\src\app\CodeFirst\bin\CodeFirst.dll.config"
```

I reached out to the EF team, and apparently things will be better in EF7: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/2974

Comment: I'm using the vnext build system and used your suggestion to get past my previous errors, thanks!  I'm not able to pick up my "transformed" web.config.release connection string though, it's using my default connection string, any ideas on how to have migrate.exe pick up the transformed connection string?

Comment: Did you add the .dll.config?  In your original question you were using web.config

Comment: The important part is that you specify exactly the .config that you need to use.  (the one that contains the connection strings is the one that you need)

Comment: Your answer worked for me - using the .dll.config was the answer I was looking for.
I also managed to get relative path working (so you can just put the .bat file in the project root):
using the command 'CD /D %~dp0' sets current directory

my entire .bat file is :
<code>
    CD /D %~dp0
    
    SET MigrateExe=packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\tools\migrate.exe
    
    %MigrateExe% NameOfDLL.dll Configuration /startUpDirectory:"%~dp0\NameOfDLL\bin\Debug" /startUpConfigurationFile:"%~dp0\NameOfDLL\bin\Debug\NameOfDLL.dll.config"

Comment: It does indeed need the full path. What a horrible little bug.

Comment: I don't think this can use a web.config *transform* file. It always uses the main web.config file for the active project, so.. you'd have to manually modify that file to point to the right environment. We do this manually when running update-database in the Visual Studio package manager console.

Answer (score 4):

Those of us just starting to use this tool might find this PowerShell script useful - it contains some default values for some common use cases:

```
Param(
    [string]$DbConnectionString,
    [string]$StartUpDirectory,
    [string]$DataModelDllName,
    [string]$StartUpConfigurationFile = "$StartUpDirectory\$DataModelDllName.config",
    [string]$ConfigurationClassName = "Configuration",
    [string]$ConnectionProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient",
    [string]$MigrateToolPath = "$PSScriptRoot\migrate.exe"
)

& $MigrateToolPath $DataModelDllName $ConfigurationClassName /startUpConfigurationFile=$StartUpConfigurationFile /connectionString=$DbConnectionString /connectionProviderName=$ConnectionProviderName  /startUpDirectory=$StartUpDirectory
```