# using migrate.exe from powershell script

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

As part of my continuous integration flow I need to apply the latest migration generated by EntityFramework to a database.

After some research I learned I can use the following script to accomplish that.

```
#copy migrate.exe to path\to\project\binfolder
Copy-Item packages\EntityFramework*\tools\migrate.exe path\to\project\binFolder

#apply latest migration
path\to\project\binFolder\migrate.exe pathto\projectGenerated.dll /startupConfigurationFile = "pathTo\Web.config"
```

I am saving this in a file and using power shell to run it.

I have two connection strings inside the web.config file like the following

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="firstConnName" connectionString="connectionstring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="secondConnName" connectionString="connectionstring" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And in code I have the following so that entity framework uses secondConnName

```
public partial class myContext : DbContext
{
    static myContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<repreeContext>(null);
    }

    public myContext()
        : base("Name=secondConnName")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
```

...

I ran the powershell script above and this is the error i am getting

System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingException: No connection string named 'secondConnName' could be fo
und in the application config file.
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)

ERROR: No connection string named 'secondConnName' could be found in the 
application config file.

Using EntityFramework 5.0, and Powershell 4.0

Any idea where I went wrong?

Thanks for the help

Comment: What's your path look like (relative, full)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724546/cant-run-code-first-migrations-using-migrate-exe/29853289#29853289

Comment: i tried both. when i tried full path though i got a different error saying "ERROR: The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

Comment: Try moving and running migrate.exe from the same folder as your projectGenerated.dll

Comment: that was what I did. I'll try running migrate.exe directly from packages/EF5.0/tools folder.

Comment: When we've had this error in Visual Studio, it was because the default startup project was not set correctly. Not sure how that would apply to calling the command line tool though.