# Cant run Entityframework code first migrations on VSTS using Migrate.exe

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-devops, entity-framework-migrations

I get the following error when I run the migrate.exe on VSTS with following arguments. I have no clue what the error is suggesting. My.dll is in the same directory as migrate.exe.

```
D:\a\r1\a\_Build My API\drop\Migrations\migrate.exe" My.dll 
/connectionString="Server=tcp:sqlserv-XXXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial 
Catalog=sqldb-portal;Persist Security Info=False;User 
ID=sqluseracct;Password=mypass;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True; 
TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" 
/connectionProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" /verbose
```

> 2018-10-06T17:22:15.2556319Z
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingException: The type
>   initializer for
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration 1 threw an
>   exception. 2018-10-06T17:22:15.2556933Z    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner) 2018-10-06T17:22:15.2557546Z    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Run()
>   2018-10-06T17:22:15.2557722Z    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)
>   2018-10-06T17:22:15.2557855Z ERROR: The type initializer for
>   'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1' threw an
>   exception.

Comment: Do you use microsoft hosted agent or self hosted agent? Does the command work on your local machine?

Comment: Hosted Agent. Nope its doesn't work on local as well. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724546/cant-run-code-first-migrations-using-migrate-exe) and it gives me ERROR: The argument 'nameOrConnectionString' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.