# Migrate.Exe Entity Framework Null Exception Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to use migrate.exe in my work project and i'm getting the following error.

> Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Console.Program.Main(String[] args)

The Command:

```
d:\Publish\bin>migrate.exe Example.Data.dll /connectionProviderName:"System.Data.SqlClient" /connectionString: "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=ExampleDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

The migrate.exe and the migrate.exe.config file are kept in the bin folder of the Publish while executing this command.

I have gone through this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705241/what-is-the-correct-format-for-running-entity-framework-migrate-exe-tool-without) and also this [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj618307.aspx) but am not able to figure out what is missing.

I created a test console project and was able to execute the process successfully with similar configurations except that instead of dll it was an exe.

Any help appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Assuming the colon instead of equal and the white space don't matter? I only ask since the error indicates a parameter issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `startupDirectory` parameter as it is described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx